# string array pattern in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

There's one pattern I like on bash scripts which commands have too complex options:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
PROGRAM_FLAGS=(
        --someoption # my comments for setting such option
        --otheropen=4 # my reasoning for using 4
        # --otheropen=5 # a commented out alternative for easy experimentation
)
PROGRAM_CALL="program ${PROGRAM_FLAGS[@]}"
```

Is there any way to use this pattern on Makefiles? Ideally in a portable way, but if not possible for gnumake?

Comment: Side note: the usual (primary) reason for putting command arguments in an array is to preserve each one's individual identity, allowing them to be quoted properly when expanded into the command. Such a command would be *executed* like so: `program "${PROGRAM_FLAGS[@]}"`.  This approach is highly recommended, but pre-expanding the command into a variable (`PROGRAM_CALL`) throws all that away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps if you describe in text what it is you want: else only people who are versed in Bash array syntax will know what your example means.

You can use this:

```
PROGRAM_FLAGS += --someoption # my comments for setting such option
PROGRAM_FLAGS += --otheropen=4 # my reasoning for using 4
# PROGRAM_FLAGS += --otheropen=5 # a commented out alternative for easy experimentation

PROGRAM_CALL = program ${PROGRAM_FLAGS}
```

This is portable IF your version of make is conforming to the very latest POSIX standards.  `+=` was not available in earlier versions of POSIX.  In those versions, there's no option except to create differently-named variables and add them all in one at a time.

Comment: That allows each option to be commented individually, but it should be noted that it has different semantics than the OP's Bash array does, especially for expansion, because `make` does not have arrays (nor the shell's sense of "words").  On the other hand, the OP's example doesn't appear to be leveraging those in the conventional way, so maybe this is moot.

Comment: Yes, I only gave a make-based replacement for the example provided in the question, since that's all the information we have. If the OP wanted to use other features of bash array variables than what the example shows, they need to describe those uses (this is why I suggested writing the requirements out rather than relying solely on an example to be translated).

Comment: That's the current workaround i've been using. When i wrote this question I was only concerned about the extra verbosity and wanted a way to remove the variable repetition. But as @JohnBollinger mentioned on both comments, i'm not benefiting from the escaping features i thought i was too. I will accept this and write a better question later! thanks!